@SpringBootTest Writing Test Case for @Service Class but @Value not populated
I am working with Spring boot 3.0.3 and I am writing test case for a Service class.
I am using @SpringBootTest and Junit5.
Test is running but problem is I have @Value injection from property file but Once I run the test It is null. Interestingly if I inject same property in Test class itself it is working fine.
@Service
Class Service{
@Value(some.value) private String someValue; // It is null when test is running
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ServiceTest {
@Value(some.value) private String someValue; // It is working here
@InjectMocks
private Service service; // Service has some mocks 
}

Any idea what is wrong ?
I want that @Value shoud work in service as expected when running the test case.
Update : If I use @Autowired instead of @InjectMcks it works but I have to inject a mock as well.

If you mock the service, then the service is not build like in a spring context.
Better to use an interface for service, then it is easier to mock ( interfaces have no injections ).

you need to either supply a application-test.yml file with the values defined
or you could leverage the ReflectionTestUtils for the same
For example in your case
this would work
@BeforeEach
public void setup(){
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, “someValue”, “set value here”);
}


This happens because @InjectMocks injects a mock service into your test, not the real service. You need to inject the real service into your test using @Autowired to get the @Value value.
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ServiceTest {
  
  @InjectMocks
  private Service mockService;
  
  @Autowired
  private Service realService;
}


mockService - this is not a real service, it is needed to test components that depend on it.
realService - this is a real service in which there will be a value @Value.


@InjectMocks private Service service; makes Mockito create a new instance of the class and inject any mocks (@Mock-annotated fields). @Value on the other hand is a Spring annotation and only works if used within a Spring bean. @InjectMocks does not create a Spring bean.
If you need a bean, you must autowire the bean @Autowired in your test:
@SpringBootTest
class ServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  private Service service;
}

This will properly populate any @Value annotated field or constructor parameter in your service.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with the following remark in your question:

Update : If I use @Autowired instead of @InjectMcks it works but I have to inject a mock as well.

If you want to mock your service, then you are no longer using the service, you are using a mocked version of it. The mock instance of the service will neither have any fields nor any behavior, unless you define the behavior of a method by stubbing it.
If you meant that your service requires additional dependencies that you want to mock, define those dependencies as @MockBean to have Spring Boot create a Mockito mock instance of the class and then register it in the application context:
@SpringBootTest
class ServiceTest {
  @MockBean
  private Dependency yourServiceDependency;
  
  @Autowired
  private Service service;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    Mockito.when(yourServiceDependency.aMethodCall(...))
      .thenReturn("stubbed result");
  }
}

This last part is impossible to properly answer without seeing an MRE.
